# Add new column with zipped list as a constant value in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have payspark dataframe and I want to add new column with constant value **x**, which is zipped list:

```
x = [('1', 'hello'),('2', 'Hi'),('3', 'Hello')]
```

But when I run this code :

```
df = df.withColumn('case', x)
```

I get this error:

```
AssertionError: col should be Column
```

How can I give struct to this list for handling this error, I know for int or string value we can use **Lit** function, but for this format I don't Know what to do.

Answer (score 1):

You could put **`string literals`** in **`structs`** into an **`array`**.

```
x = [('1', 'hello'),('2','Hi'),('3', 'Hello')]

df.withColumn("col1", F.array(*[F.struct(F.lit(i[0]),F.lit(i[1])) for i in x])).show(truncate=False)

+---------------------------------+
|col1                             |
+---------------------------------+
|[[1, hello], [2, Hi], [3, Hello]]|
|[[1, hello], [2, Hi], [3, Hello]]|
+---------------------------------+
```

**`Or`**, you create an **`array`** of **`arrays`**:

```
x = [('1', 'hello'),('2','Hi'),('3', 'Hello')]

df.withColumn("col1", F.array(*[F.array(F.lit(i[0]),F.lit(i[1])) for i in x])).show(truncate=False)

+---------------------------------+
|col1                             |
+---------------------------------+
|[[1, hello], [2, Hi], [3, Hello]]|
|[[1, hello], [2, Hi], [3, Hello]]|
+---------------------------------+
```

**`Or`**, you could use **`create_map`** in a similar fashion:

```
x = [('1', 'hello'),('2','Hi'),('3', 'Hello')]

df.withColumn("col1",F.array(*[F.create_map(F.lit(i[0]),F.lit(i[1])) for i in x])).show(truncate=False)

+---------------------------------------+
|col1                                   |
+---------------------------------------+
|[[1 -> hello], [2 -> Hi], [3 -> Hello]]|
|[[1 -> hello], [2 -> Hi], [3 -> Hello]]|
+---------------------------------------+
```

Comment: it works well, but with pandas dataframe I use this column to apply function but in pyspark it has problem, maybe I should change input type in my udf, Thanks  for your help